# Show $\frac{d}{dt} | v(t)|^2 = 2a(t)v(t)$

Tags: calculus

Is this correct?
A particle moves with position vector $r(t) = xi + yj + zk$.  Let $v(t) = r'(t),\  a(t) = r''(t)$
Then $$\frac{1}{2}\,\frac{d}{dt}|v(t)|^2 = \frac{1}{2}*2|v(t)|v'(t) = v(t) \cdot  a(t)$$ by chain rule.

No, right? because $|v(t)|$ isn't differentiable? and $v(t) \neq |v(t)|$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$|\vec{v(t)}|^2 = \vec{v(t)} \cdot \vec{v(t)}$$

$$\frac{d}{dt}(|\vec{v(t)}|^2) = \frac{d}{dt}(\vec{v(t)} \cdot \vec{v(t)}) = \vec{v'(t)}\cdot \vec{v(t)} + \vec{v(t)}\cdot \vec{v'(t)} = 2\vec{v'(t)}\cdot \vec{v(t)} = 2\vec{a(t)}\cdot \vec{v(t)}$$

(I used product rule (as applied to the vector dot product) and the commutativity of the dot product).